# Updating empty cells in pandas dataframe with return values from a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe called `df1`:

```
  link       header     desc1  desc2
0 xxx-xxx-1  xxx xxx 1  12354  123
1 xxx-xxx-2  
2 xxx-xxx-3  xxx xxx 3  231    1126
3 xxx-xxx-4  
...
```

I want to create a function that checks if the header is missing from a row, and use the `somefunction` below to fill in the blanks in that row.

```
def somefunction(link):
    ...    
    return {"header": header,
             .....
           }
```

The function is used like so, `somefunction("xxx-xxx-2")`.
The output would look like this for example:

```
{"header": "xxx xxx 2",
 "desc1": "5325",
 "desc2": "5661",}
```

Depending on the link, the function will return different dictionary values.

The updated result of that should look like this,

```
  link       header     desc1  desc2
0 xxx-xxx-1  xxx xxx 1  12354  123
1 xxx-xxx-2  xxx xxx 2  5325   5661
2 xxx-xxx-3  xxx xxx 3  231    1126
3 xxx-xxx-4
```

So far I have got this,

```
for idx,row in df1.iterrows():
   if row['header'].isna():
       returndict = somefunction(row['header'])
   else:
       continue
```

How do I fill-in the blanks with the values from the return function? Should it be some other format? Usually I would just create a dictionary of the values and convert it to a dataframe. Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: (1) what's the expected output? (2) are you familiar with fillna?

Comment: sorry I've updated my question. The only thing I've used fillna for is to fill ALL blank values with the SAME value. However my function will return a different value based on the link

Comment: What's the input of this function? Is it a constant value for all the rows, or a different value based on some other field in the row?

Comment: the input is the link, from the first link column. the output will be different based on the link provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. I'm using a dummy function in this case:

```
# Create a dummy dataframe. 
df = pd.DataFrame({"link": range(5), "header": [1, 2, None, 3, None], "desc1": [2, 3, None, 4, None]})
print(df)

   link  header  desc1
0     0     1.0    2.0
1     1     2.0    3.0
2     2     NaN    NaN
3     3     3.0    4.0
4     4     NaN    NaN

def foo(link):
    return link, link * 2, link * link

df.loc[df.header.isna()] = df.loc[df.header.isna(), "link"].apply(foo).to_list()
print(df)


   link  header  desc1
0   0.0     1.0    2.0
1   1.0     2.0    3.0
2   2.0     4.0    4.0
3   3.0     3.0    4.0
4   4.0     8.0   16.0
```

---

If you'd like your function to return a dict rather than a list or a tuple, you can do the following:

```
def foo(link):
    return {
        "link": link, 
        "header": link * 2, 
        "desc1": link * link
    }

dicts = df.loc[df.header.isna(), "link"].apply(foo) 

df.loc[df.header.isna()] = pd.DataFrame(list(dicts), index = df.loc[df.header.isna(), "link"].index)

print(df)
```

Comment: so I must return a tuple?

Comment: Doing it this way, you can also return a list of values.

Comment: ok I understand. is there a safe way to do it like returning a dictionary so that I can make sure the correct column accepts the correct answer?

Comment: Let me think about it for a couple of minutes.